# Robotframework throws error while evaluation a return value

Tags: robotframework

I have below code in a Robot script:

```
${RC}=    Run Process    ${CURDIR}/my.bat    ${CURDIR}    ${target}
Run Keyword If    ${RC} != 0     Stop Test    "Error BATCH"
```

I get below error:

```
Evaluating expression '<result object with rc 0> != 0' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>,line1)
```

I tried many ways like *= 'PASS'* or other ways but still I get the same issue - the batch file will either return 0 or %ERRORLEVEL%

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Run Process` keyword returns an object. If you want to access the `return code` or `rc` from the object you should use `${variableName.rc}`.

In your case, the code should be changed as follows:

```
${RC}=    Run Process    ${CURDIR}/my.bat    ${CURDIR}    ${target}
Run Keyword If    ${RC.rc} != 0     Stop Test    "Error BATCH"
```

To access other values from the object check [this section](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Result%20object) from the `Process` library documentation.